# HTML checkbox and radio button add+subtract

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have reached this point and I cannot find a solution to where I am going wrong.

1. What I have done is that when I check one of the checkboxes, it adds a value to the total, but when I uncheck it, it does not subtract the value.
2. The other issue is that if I check the checkbox and one of the two radio buttons, it does not add the new value and it removes the value of the checkbox.

This is part of the HTML code. This script calculates the value, but I haven't done it correctly. I would appreciate it if someone could provide some advice.

Please disregard the Cyrillic text.

```js
var price_string = $('#total-price').val();

function add_delivery_cost(val) {

  var delivery_cost = parseFloat(val); //Converting to float value//Returns  24.00
  var price = parseFloat(price_string); // Converting to float value
  // Adding delivery cost to price and rounding to 2 decimal points
  var total_price = (price + delivery_cost).toFixed(2); 
  var price_html = '' + total_price;
  
  // Updating the `html` content of total-price with a new value after adding delivery cost to the price.
  $('#total-price-td').html(price_html); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="group" type="radio" name="rb" value='4.90' onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" />

<input class="group1" type="checkbox" value='13.95' name="rb" id="total" onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" />

<input class="group2" type="radio" name="rb" value='5.90' onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" />

<input class="group3" type="radio" ng-model='mValue' value="" checked="checked" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="div24">Междинна сума:</div>
  <div class="div25">27.90лв</div>
  <div class="div26">4.90лв</div>
  <div class="div27">Общо:</div>
  <div class="div28">Информация</div>
  <div class="frame-child12"></div>
  <div class="frame-child13"></div>
  <div class="frame-child14"></div>
  <img class="removal-3-icon" alt="" src="./public/removal-3@2x.png" />

  <div class="div29">
    <p class="p"> тест</p>
    <p class="p">Над 400 числа</p>
    <p class="p">друг тест,</p>
    <p class="p">много</p>
    <p class="p">други.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div30">68.00 лв.</div>
  <div class="div31">72.90 лв.</div>
  <div class="div32">27.90лв.</div>
  <div class="div33" id="total-price-td">27.90лв.</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="total-price" value="27.90">
```

I want that when I check the checkbox, it adds the value to the total price, and when I uncheck it, it subtracts the value from the total price.

The problem is also that when I check the checkbox and then click on one of the two radio buttons above, it removes the value of the checkbox and only adds the value of the selected radio button.

Comment: It sounds first and foremost to me like you are using checkboxes and radio buttons inappropriately for their intended purpose.

Comment: I am a beginner in HTML and JS. Any advise?